# Is there a generic authentication module that can be used in any PHP website?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I am developping a simple website and I am pretty new to PHP. Currently I made a simple HTML authentication page that just redirect the user to index.php. From there, the user can logout or modify his password.

Since almost all websites are using such authentication systems, I was wondering if there is an API or an existing module that could handle that for me: Log in a user, Reset password by email, Modify password and Logout.

I really want to make it simple but still secure. The goal is to not waste too much time on coding such a generic feature and having to handle all security issues (such as SQL injection, etc...).

Does a very simple solution exist or do I have to implement the whole thing by myself?

Comment: This is what various frameworks provide you, but as to being a simple solution, that's another thing altogether.

Comment: Yes, when I was looking for this, I found out frameworks (Laravel and Symfony) were way too heavy for my concern. Also, I already implemented many features in pure PHP and I am afraid that switching to a framework would make me having to restart from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a framework, or  component of a framework like Symfony, not only for your application but DEFINITELY for your authentication.  You are exposing yourself to a great deal of probable risk by trying to roll your own authentication or by trying to utilise someone's custom shot at doing a lightweight version on github. The reason authentication in these frameworks can seem 'too heavy' (as you put it) is because there are a multitude of attack vectors and framework contributors have gone to a great deal of hard work to find them out and ensure the framework is safe.  Frameworks are your friend and something like Laravel is incredibly easy to get started with. So the best advice would be to adopt one and accept that they're often big because they've done so much leg work for you.